# Is it true that if a non-negative function is Riemann integrable, there must exist an upper sum U(f)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I know that if the upper sum of f, $U(f)$ equals the lower sum of f on an interval $[a,b]$ then f is Riemann integrable on [a,b] with $U(f)=L(f)= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx.$

Is the reverse true? That is if f is riemann integrable is it the case that there must exists an U(f) and L(f) with $U(f)=L(f)= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx.$?

Edit:
My books gives the following:

A bounded function $f$ defined on the interval [a,b] is Riemann integrable if $U(f) = L(f).$ In this case we define $\int_{a}^{b} f$ or $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ to be $\int_{a}^{b} f = U(f) = L(f).$

They don't use "if and only if" so i was note sure whether it was the case that if f is riemann integrable then there must exists an U(f) and L(f) with $U(f)=L(f)= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx.$?

Comment: Isn't the existence and equality of what you call $ U(f) $ and $ L(f) $ the definition of what it means for $ f $ to be Riemann integrable?  If not, then what does your text/resource consider to be the definition of Riemann Integrability?

Comment: This is the definition in my book:

But first $U(f) = inf\{ U(f,P): P \in X\}$ where X is the collection of all possible partitions. And  $L(f) = sup\{ U(f,P): P \in X\}$.

The book defines Riemann Integrability to be: A bounded function $f$ defined on the interval [a,b] is Riemann integrable if $U(f) = L(f).$ In this case we define $\int_{a}^{b} f$ or $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ to be $\int_{a}^{b} f = U(f) = L(f).$ The reason I asked this question is because they didn't use "if and only if."

Comment: Please accept my answer below then.  You simply had confusion about mathematical parlance, not the mathematics itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a book uses the phrasing, "We say that an A has property P if condition C holds", they mean "exactly if" or "if and only if".  Just using the word "if" is a universal shorthand for mathematical definitions.

Comment: When you think about it, this is the way definitions should work, because it would be pretty  silly to say, "We say that an A has property P if condition C" holds, but you didn't mean "only if".  Because then the mathematical community would be left with an ambiguous definition: if they ever encountered an A without condition C, it would be ambiguous as to whether A has property P or not.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $U(f)$ always exist to be the infimum of upper sums over partitions. So any bounded function (which includes Riemann integrable functions) would have an upper sum.